What is the purpose of `enum class` with a specified underlying type, but no enumerators?
The std::align_val_t type is defined as:
namespace std
{
    enum class align_val_t : size_t
    {
    };
}

What is the purpose of such an empty enumeration?
What's the difference with a typedef?

It’s not without values; it’s without named values. Enumerated types can hold values outside their set of named values.

@PeteBecker There's a weird gotcha: only enums with a specified underlying type can do that.

Related: Why should std::align_val_t restrict implicit conversion?

@PasserBy — that not how I remember it. C-style enumerated types can hold any value that fits in the bits that represent the values of the enumerators. enum mask { one = 1, two = 2 }; mask three = one | two; to emphasize that it’s a bitmask, but mask three = 3; is also okay. mask four = 4; is not allowed, because it needs an additional bit. But, of course, if there are no enumerators there are no bits, and no value can be stored. That’s not weird; it just follows from the delineation of the allowable values.

@PeteBecker you're right - supporting C++23 quote: "For an enumeration whose underlying type is fixed, the values of the enumeration are the values of the underlying type. Otherwise, the values of the enumeration are the values representable by a  hypothetical integer type with minimal width M such that all enumerators can be represented. The width of the smallest bit-field large enough to hold all the values of the enumeration type is M ."

@PeteBecker It's interesting. But I tested your code in C++11, and the compiler tells me that there is an invalid conversion from int to the enum where I do the assignment.

@TonyDelroy that's just language-lawyer weasel wording to let the compiler writers get away with shenanigans.  It's highly unlikely that a 2-bit integer would be used as the backing store for an enumeration.

@Oodini -- whoops, you're right: a cast is needed.

@MarkRansom -- that "weasel wording" is about specifying behavior without constricting implementations to a particular set of integer types. Needing only two bits to represent the enumerators is an edge case, but it's controlled by the general rule, not by "it's highly unlikely...".

@MarkRansom I guess they worded it like that so if there are enums stored side-by-side in a struct, they can - at the compiler's discretion - be packed as efficiently as possible across the available bits.  For enum values that aren't in a struct, it's hard to image they'd ever go less than a byte, but I guess with the rules the way they are they could e.g. shift a non-struct field and add it to an intra-struct enum field without checking for higher bits, knowing they won't clobber anything unless you yourself violated the Standard's requirements.

@TonyDelroy Probably not only at the compiler's discretion. That could work when using padding.

@TonyDelroy: A compiler that smartly packs enum-typed variables together will have a very hard time satisfying the race condition rules.  If you ask for a bit field, the compiler doesn't have to do that, but if it infers them, it has to act as-if they are full words.  Treatment of addresses could also be problematic.

It is used as a strongly typed integer, which disables implicit type conversions.
enum class strong_typed : size_t {};

typedef size_t defed;

int strong(strong_typed f);
int weak(defed f);

int main()
{
    weak(defed{5}); // works
    weak(5); // works

    strong(strong_typed{5}); // works
    strong(5);               // error cannot convert int to strong_typed
    strong(size_t{5});       // error cannot convert size_t to strong_typed
}

godbolt demo
you can get back the underlying type with std::to_underlying inside the function.
Strongly typed integers are useful when you have a function accepting many arguments of the same type and you want to disambiguate them to avoid swapping arguments by mistake, or invoking the wrong overload.

As for why it is used in std::align_val_t, according to Ted Lyngmo in the comments, it is likely to disambiguate operator new in the variadic case.
// called by new (size_t{5}) T{};
void* operator new  ( std::size_t count, size_t arg );

// called by new T{}; on a T with large alignment
void* operator new  ( std::size_t count, std::align_val_t al );


Speculation regarding why they use this strong type in the allocation functions when a plain size_t is used for count: When support for this alignment requirement was added in C++17, they needed some way to separate the alignment argument from the rest of the arguments in the variadic cases (/* args... */), otherwise yet another size_t  argument could either be the alignment or the first argument to the constructor.

It should be mentioned that the purpose of this particular type is so that you can overload void* operator new(std::size_t size, std::align_val_t alignment); (either the global one or a class-specific one).  Declaring both arguments as size_t would invite accidentally putting them in the wrong order.  It would also create the ambiguity with varargs that @TedLyngmo mentioned.

cppreference provides roughly the same explanation for it: "Alignment (as obtained by alignof) has the type std::size_t, but placement forms of allocation and deallocation functions that take std::size_t as an additional parameter are already in use, so this type is used instead."

So after -- what is it, four decades? -- C++ has finally caught up with Ada83's derived types! The "bare metal" crowd has a hard time coming around to built-in safety features.

Great answer!  Is there any other way to disable implicit conversions?

@russoue you can always create a struct with a single member and give it a constructor that is marked explicit. But you will need to write an equality and less than operators and a hash function. The above is much shorter if you only store an integer.
